# Equivalent of base64 -d in Javascript

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, base64, mp3, audio-streaming

My code submits an HTTP request for synthesizing speech to GCP Text-to-Speech. Suppose that the resulting audio stream is stored in the variable `audioContent`. When I use this code in `Node.js`, I am able to do `console.log(audioContent)` and produce a valid mp3 file as follows (assuming that my code is stored in `server.js`:

```
node.exe server.js > response.txt
base64 response.txt -d > response.mp3
```

The file `response.mp3` plays as expected, hence I know that `audioContent` contains a valid audio stream.

My goal is to have this work in `React.js`. Here is the relevant code. It uses `js-base64` for decoding, but I tried `atob()` as well without success:

```
let binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(Base64.decode(audioContent));
const url = myURL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "audio/mp3"}))
document.querySelector("a").href = url;
```

For some reason, the downloaded file is not a valid mp3. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what was wrong with my code, but this is what worked (inspired by [this example](https://ionicframework.com/blog/converting-a-base64-string-to-a-blob-in-javascript/)):

```
fetch(`data:mpeg;base64,${audioContent}`).
then(res=>res.blob()).
then(blob=>{ 
        const myURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
        const url = myURL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], {type: 'audio/mp3'}));
        document.querySelector("a").href = url;
})
```